# No matching function for call to getline()?

Tags: c++, macos, getline

Every time I try to build this code I get an error,

> "No matching function for call to getline()"

But I've used it before and it worked fine? S I'm not sure what's going on. I'm using Mavericks OSX if that would be anything, and using Xcode to build this project. It's for school. I know the inputFile is working correctly, because I have commented the getline() and "Open" printed to the console.

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  Project 4
//
//  Created by Eric Diviney on 10/27/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Eric Diviney. All rights reserved.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    /*
    |
    |-------------------------------------------------------------
    |   Documentation
    |-------------------------------------------------------------
    |   The headings[] array will contain all strings for the customer's receipt.
    |   the 2nd level of headings[][] will contain all of the info (name, address etc.) while
    |   the first level of headings[] will contain the number of customers. The order of the second level is heading1, heading2, customername,
    |   address, phone, footer
    |
    |   The charges[] array will contain all double/floats required to compute the charges for the customer.
    |   The third level of charges[][][] will contain the actual charges/prices while the first level
    |   will hold n amount of customers. The second level of that array (charges[][]) will hold the first, second and third month.
    |   The order of the last array is electricity, water, and gas
    |
    |   The output[] array is 3 customers in the first level (output[]) and the correspnding strings for each
    |   segment of their receipt output[][]. The order in the second level of this array is heading1, heading2, customerName, Customer address, 
    |   customer Phone, Customer ID, electricity, water, gas, subtotal, discountRate, taxRate, tax for order, discount for order, order total,
    |   footer
    |
     */

    // variable declarations
    string headings[3][7];
    double charges[3][3][3];
    string output[3][16];

    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("/Users/ericdiviney/Documents/workspace/project4/project4/input.txt");
    if(inputFile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Open" << endl;
    }

    getline(inputFile, headings[0][0], "*");
    //cout << headings[0][0];

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The third parameter is a single character, so you need

```
getline(inputFile, headings[0][0], '*');
```

Note the single quotes. `"*"` is a null-terminated string literal, with type `const char[2]`.

Comment: You, my friend, are the greatest human being alive. Thank you! Haha I will checkmark the answer once this little 11-minute limit thing runs out. Thank you so so so much!!